# Learning rate scheduler in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to recreate results of “The Lottery Ticket  Hypothesis” by Frankle et al. in PyTorch. They are using CIFAR-10 which has 50K  training images. Using a batch size = 64 gives 781 iterations/steps in  one epoch. I am trying to implement this in PyTorch.

For VGG-18 & ResNet-18, the authors propose the following learning rate schedule

1. Linear learning rate warmup for first k = 7813 steps from 0.0 to 0.1

After 10 epochs or 7813 training steps, the learning rate schedule is as follows-

1. For the next 21094 training steps (or, 27 epochs), use a learning rate of 0.1
2. For the next 13282 training steps (or, 17 epochs), use a learning rate of 0.01
3. For any remaining training steps, use a learning rate of 0.001

I have implemented this in TensorFlow2 as follows:

```
from typing import Callable, List, Optional, Union

class WarmUp(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    """
    Applies a warmup schedule on a given learning rate decay schedule.
    Args:
        initial_learning_rate (:obj:`float`):
            The initial learning rate for the schedule after the warmup (so this will be the learning rate at the end
            of the warmup).            
        decay_schedule_fn (:obj:`Callable`):
            The schedule function to apply after the warmup for the rest of training.        
        warmup_steps (:obj:`int`):
            The number of steps for the warmup part of training.        
        power (:obj:`float`, `optional`, defaults to 1):
            The power to use for the polynomial warmup (defaults is a linear warmup).        
        name (:obj:`str`, `optional`):
            Optional name prefix for the returned tensors during the schedule.
    """
    def __init__(
        self,
        initial_learning_rate: float,
        decay_schedule_fn: Callable,
        warmup_steps: int,
        power: float = 1.0,
        name: str = None,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.initial_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate
        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps
        self.power = power
        self.decay_schedule_fn = decay_schedule_fn
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, step):
        with tf.name_scope(self.name or "WarmUp") as name:
            # Implements polynomial warmup. i.e., if global_step < warmup_steps, the
            # learning rate will be `global_step/num_warmup_steps * init_lr`.
            global_step_float = tf.cast(step, tf.float32)
            warmup_steps_float = tf.cast(self.warmup_steps, tf.float32)
            warmup_percent_done = global_step_float / warmup_steps_float
            warmup_learning_rate = self.initial_learning_rate * tf.math.pow(warmup_percent_done, self.power)
            return tf.cond(
                global_step_float < warmup_steps_float,
                lambda: warmup_learning_rate,
                lambda: self.decay_schedule_fn(step - self.warmup_steps),
                name=name,
            )

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            "initial_learning_rate": self.initial_learning_rate,
            "decay_schedule_fn": self.decay_schedule_fn,
            "warmup_steps": self.warmup_steps,
            "power": self.power,
            "name": self.name,
        }

boundaries = [21093, 34376]
values = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]

learning_rate_fn = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay(boundaries, values)

warmup_shcedule = WarmUp(initial_learning_rate = 0.1, decay_schedule_fn = learning_rate_fn, warmup_steps = 7813)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = warmup_shcedule, momentum = 0.9, decay = 0.0, nesterov = False)
```

I then train model using “tf.GradientTape” and view the learning rate as follows:

```
optimizer._decayed_lr('float32').numpy()
```

The resulting learning rate during the 60 epochs of training can be viewed visually as:

[image: learning rate schedule]

You can access the complete TF2 code [here](https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/CNN_Classifications/blob/master/VGG18_Train_from_scratch-LR_Warmup_%26_Step_Decay.ipynb).

How can I achieve the same learning rate scheduler in torch?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can set custom LRs using LambdaLR.

```py
import torch

def warmup(base_lr, current_step, warmup_steps, boundaries, values):
    
    #warmup phase
    if current_step < warmup_steps:
        return float(current_step / warmup_steps * base_lr)
    # check boundaries
    else:
        # first index in 'boundaries' greater than current_step
        s = next((x[0] for x in enumerate(boundaries) if x[1] > current_step), -1)
        return values[s-1]
    
    
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=warmup)
# lr_scheduler.step() for using it in your training loop
```

If you plot the returned LR for each step by:

```py
max_steps = 40000
base_lr = 0.1
boundaries = [7813, 21093, 34376, float('inf')]
values = [base_lr, 0.01, 0.001, 0]
warmup_steps = 7813

for current_step in range(1, max_steps):
    x.append(current_step)
    y.append(warmup(base_lr, current_step, warmup_steps, boundaries, values))
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

You will get:

[image]